# Portlet superclass must be a valid portlet class

Tags: eclipse, maven, liferay

I'm using liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2 with maven 2.2.1.. and I'd like to create a new portlet!!
when I click New>liferay-portlet... using eclipse. After creating the portlet I found 2 errors in portlet.xml and pom.xml!

portlet.xml:

...
        javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet
...

the error : The class javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet was not found on the Java Build Path.

pom.xml:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution><!-- the error is here -->
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-css</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

the error: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:${liferay.maven.plugin.version}:build-css 
 (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the maven error, I'm not sure but it seems that the `liferay.maven.plugin.version` property is missing (I'd expect it would get replaced with an actual value in the error message if the value was resolvable by maven)

As for the *The class javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet was not found on the Java Build Path* error: you said that you used some `New>liferay-portlet`, so I assume you are using Liferay Developer Studio. From my experience (and this is my subjective opinion), it seems that Liferay put much more emphasis on it's ant SDK and general ant integration so Liferay DS (at least – at the moment) may not work well with a maven-based portlet project. I guess it missed some dependency in pom.xml, so simply verify if `jsf-portlet-bridge-api.jar` is in dependencies in pom.xml